# Trying to fill in a List of class

Tags: list, class, flutter, dart

I'm really sorry I'm such a beginner...
At the end I just have a list of 8 TimeCardDayStrip with the same name/position when it'd supposed to be the 8 different names/roles.
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here:
thank you very much

```
'''
class TimeCardDayStrip {
  String name, position;
  DateTime day;

  @override
  String toString(){
    return '{ $this.name, $this.position }';
  }
}

void main() {
  var tcds = TimeCardDayStrip();
  var listOfTcds = [];
  List<String> names, roles;
   names = ["Michael", "Gunnell", "Byrne", "Aspromonte", "Davis", "Adam Jordan", "Mirko"];
  roles = ["Director", "Vice", "President", "1ST", "KEY 2ND", "2ND", "BASECAMP PA", "PA", " PA", "Add'l PA"];

  for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    tcds.name = names[i];
    tcds.position = roles[i];
    listOfTcds.add(tcds);
    // checking the list as it creates
    print(listOfTcds[i].name+' is '+listOfTcds[i].position);
  }
  //print the list of card to check
  print('print the list of time card to check');
  for (int x = 0; x < listOfTcds.length; x++){
    print (listOfTcds.elementAt(x).name);
  }
}
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to print out each name: 
Put this within the loop (you should create new object each loop instead of updating the same one)

```
 for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {

    var tcds = TimeCardDayStrip();

    tcds.name = names[i];
    tcds.position = roles[i];
    listOfTcds.add(tcds);

    // checking the list as it creates
    print('${listOfTcds[i].name} is ${listOfTcds[i].position}');
}
```

Then later

```
 listOfTcds[x].name
```

If you want to display stuff:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctx) {
    return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: listOfTcds.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return CustomTile(item: listOfTcds[index]);
            },
          );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately the result doesn't change
...

(print the list of time card to check)
Mirko
Mirko
Mirko
Mirko
Mirko
Mirko
Mirko

Comment: You should be creating tcds as a new object within the loop each time then adding it to a list, otherwise yo are just updating value on the same pointer to the object.

Comment: Perfection! now it worked, thanks! now I'll go head and  hopefully I'll be able to return it to a function... that create my list! but this is another story! Amazing, so happy, I spent three days to try to figure out by myself! thank you so much!

Comment: Awesome, best of luck on your coding adventures!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to declare the tcds as Tcds = new TimecardDayStrip() and not just tcds = TimeCardDayStrip() or you are just changing the same object and not creating a new instance.

Comment: thanks: I thought that form Dart 2.0 new is optional, btw I've tried what you suggested but the output doesn't change: 

print the list of time card to check
Mirko
Mirko
Mirko
Mirko
Mirko
Mirko
Mirko